# Computer turns off before boot

Tags: windows, boot, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

My computer was working perfectly yesterday, but today every time I try to boot the computer, the computer randomly shuts off at any time during the boot process. Sometimes, the laptop manages to boot into the login screen, and even then it is rare to be able to get to the Desktop. I'm hoping that one time I turn it on I might become lucky enough to have enough time to get to the Event Viewer in Windows, but it feels pretty unlikely.

List of what happens:

- Sometimes turns off instantly
- Sometimes able to get to the boot screen
- Rarely able to get to log in screen, and even rarer to get to Desktop
- No boot codes or power/motherboard beeps
- Able to access BIOS, but still shuts down within a matter of seconds - couple of minutes

Any suggestions would be amazing.

The potential issues I believe could be taking place are:

- Faulty Motherboard
- Faulty PSU
- Clogged AIO CPU cooler (overheating)

Any suggestions would be amazing.

Comment: Get any hardware Diagnostics you can and run them. Particularly Disk and Memory. You can use Memtest86.exe for memory. Since it shuts down in BIOS, then memory or motherboard and CPU are at fault.

Comment: There is the potential of a PSU issue though, or a case fault. and I can't get any hardware diagnostics without being able to access the computer.

Comment: If not Memory (Memtest86) then you need to consider if it is economical to fix.

Comment: @John Most probably not economical to fix at all at the moment, but it would be useful to be able to get some diagnostics or any other ways to trouble shoot the system

Answer (score 0):

You can't get diagnostics if you can't boot.

You could try to remove as many components as you can, in the hope
of finding the faulty one. For example, remove RAM sticks until
only one is left, then change it (if you have more than one).

Otherwise,
this should be handled by a repair-shop that has spare parts to change,
so as to find the failed component. Or if you have spare components
on hand, and have the knowledge, you could try it yourself.

Buying multiple parts for replacement will be too costly and wasteful.

Comment: Even repair-shops are costly at the moment, if that's the route I take, it's going to have to wait. Can't afford that in itself at the moment.